# How to display elements to stay in the same place on all browsers and devices

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and wanted to ask you how you can align elements, images, text, nav links, etc. to stay in the same place on all browsers and devices.

First when I created my website I was coding it on my PC, then I sent the file to laptop and all the nav links, images, etc. were all over the place.

I did research and I couldn't find the right answer for my question.

I've attached the scss file, maybe can somebody explain how to correctly edit it; I've also included the home page html.

````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>GEH</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/style.css">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abyssinica+SIL&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <header class="header">
      <nav>
        <div><a href="website.html"><img src="./dist/css/images/LOGOWHite.png" id="myimage" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="website.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/concept.html">Concept</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="pages/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="pages/ourpartners.html">Our Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/howtobeourpartner.html">How To Be Our artner</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
    </header>
    </head>
    </html>
    <body>
    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>GEH is an lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmodt<br>emep por incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mini<br>eveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br> apcommodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in volupta<br> opevelit esse cillum dolore  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br>pop cupidatat non proident, officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br></p>
      </div>
    <!---JavaScript for Toggle Menu-->
    <script>
    
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
    
        function showMenu(){
          navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
        function hideMenu(){
          navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
        }
    
    </script>
    <footer class="footer1">
      <div class="CompanyInfo">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="pages/aboutus.html">  Company Info</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="Policies">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="pages/TermsandConditions.html"> Policies</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="Copyrights">
        <h3 href=""><i class="fa fa-copyright" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copyrights</h3>
      </div> 
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>GEH About Us</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/style.css">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abyssinica+SIL&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <header class="header">
      <nav>
        <!-- <div><a href="../pages/aboutus.html"><img src="../images/About Us.png" id="myimage" alt=""></a></div> -->
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="../website.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/concept.html">Concept</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="../pages/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="../pages/ourpartners.html">Our Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/howtobeourpartner.html">How To Be Our Partner</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
    </header>
    </head>
    </html>
    <body>
    
    <div class="About-Us">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br> commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in volupta<br> velit esse cillum dolore  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br> cupidatat non proident, officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br></p>
      </div>
      <div class="Project-aim">
            <h1>Project-aim</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br> commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in volupta<br> velit esse cillum dolore  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br> cupidatat non proident, officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br></p>
      </div>
      <div class="Duration">
        <h1>Duration</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br> commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in volupta<br> velit esse cillum dolore  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat<br> cupidatat non proident, officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br></p>
      </div>
    <!---JavaScript for Toggle Menu-->
    <script>
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
    
        function showMenu(){
          navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
        function hideMenu(){
          navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
        }
    
    </script>
    <footer class="footer1">
      <div class="CompanyInfo">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="../pages/aboutus.html">  Company Info</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="Policies">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="../pages/TermsandConditions.html"> Policies</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="Copyrights">
        <h3 href=""><i class="fa fa-copyright" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copyrights</h3>
      </div>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>GEH Concept</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/style.css">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abyssinica+SIL&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    </html>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../website.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="../pages/concept.html">Concept</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="../pages/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="../pages/ourpartners.html">Our Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/howtobeourpartner.html">How To Be Our Partner</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-small-image">
            <img src="../dist/css/images/EPR3-2-740x520.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <img src="../dist/css/images/Natrium-TerraPower-GEH.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <img src="../dist/css/images/GEH-Nuclear-Energy-to-recruit-First-Nations-peoples-for-field-services-jobs-.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <img src="../dist/css/images/GEH-Begins-NRC-Licensing-Process-for-BWRX-300-Small-Modular-Reactor-800x480.jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <img src="../dist/css/images/BWRX-300-SMR-rendering-(GEH).jpg" onclick="myFunction(this)">
        </div>
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="../dist/css/images/BWRX-300-SMR-rendering-(GEH).jpg" id="imageBox">
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="Concept">
        <!-- <img src="../images/gehimage.jpg" class="gehimage" alt="gehImage" width="500px" height="500px"> -->
        <h1>GEH CONCEPT</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in volupta o<br> velit esse cillum dolore  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat posd cupidatat non proident, officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumip.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br>veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex eaveniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamcoS laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea </p>
      </div>
    <!---JavaScript for Toggle Menu-->
    <script>
    
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
    
        function showMenu(){
          navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
        function hideMenu(){
          navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
        }
    
        function myFunction(smallImg)
       {
         var fullimg = document.getElementById("imageBox")
         fullimg.src = smallImg.src
       }
    
    </script>
    <footer class="footer1">
    <div class="CompanyInfo">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="../pages/aboutus.html">  Company Info</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="Policies">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="../pages/TermsandConditions.html"> Policies</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="Copyrights">
        <h3 href=""><i class="fa fa-copyright" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copyrights</h3>
      </div>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <title>GEH About Us</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/style.css">
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abyssinica+SIL&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>
        </html>
        <body>
        <header class="header">
          <nav>
            <!-- <div class="logolast"><a href="../website.html"><img src="../images/LOGOWHite.png" id="myimage1" alt=""></a></div> -->
            <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
              <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../website.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../pages/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../pages/concept.html">Concept</a></li>
                    <!-- <li><a href="../pages/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li> -->
                    <li><a href="../pages/ourpartners.html">Our Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a class="active" href="../pages/howtobeourpartner.html">How To Be Our Partner</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
          </nav>
          <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeeTGS-lDbCBx879GQx4CwvN-fja8GnN38sNRUX33dpitSWyQ/viewform?vc=0&c=0&w=1&flr=0">
            <input class="GoogleForms" type="button" value="I want to be a partner" />
         </a>
        <div class="contacts">
          <h1>CONTACTS</h1>
          <p1>City: Istanbul<br></p1>
          <p2>Phone: +1 230923 32972<br></p2>
          <p3>Email: ekjksd@gmail.com<br></p3>
        </div>
        </header>
        <!---JavaScript for Toggle Menu-->
        <script>
        
            var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
        
            function showMenu(){
              navLinks.style.right = "0";
            }
            function hideMenu(){
              navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
            }
        
        </script>
        <footer class="footer1">
          <div class="CompanyInfo">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="../pages/aboutus.html">  Company Info</a></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Policies">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="../pages/TermsandConditions.html"> Policies</a></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Copyrights">
            <h3 href=""><i class="fa fa-copyright" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copyrights</h3>
          </div>
        </footer>
        </body>
        </html>
    
```
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Abyssinica SIL", serif;
}
/* header */
.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/banner.png");
  background-size: 150vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
}
/* Links, nav links */
nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: left;
}

nav img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Text box home tab */
.text-box {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: right;
}

.text-box h1 {
  font-size: 62px;
}

.text-box p {
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: right;
}
/* Here is about us tab text boxes*/
.About-Us {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55.5%;
  left: -14%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: right;
}

.About-Us h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.About-Us p {
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
}
.Project-aim {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 61%;
  left: 18.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: right;
}

.Project-aim h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.Project-aim p {
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
}
.Duration {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66.9%;
  left: 51%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: right;
}

.Duration h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.Duration p {
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
}
.Concept {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 85%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: left;
}

.gehimage {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -750px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.Concept h1 {
  font-size: 130px;
}

.Concept p {
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
}
/* Display when opening phone */
nav .fa {
  display: none;
}
.gallery-small-image img {
  height: 62.1px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.gallery-small-image img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-small-image {
  float: left;
}

.gallery {
  top: 57.8%;
  left: 20%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.img-container img {
  height: 350px;
  width: 650px;
}

.img-container {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* Our Partners Name*/
.partnerstitle {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 220px;
}
/* Contacts */
.contacts {
  color: #fff;
}

.contacts h1 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 55px;
  bottom: 800px;
  left: 130px;
  position: fixed;
}

.contacts p1 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 620px;
  left: 130px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.contacts p2 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 440px;
  left: 130px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.contacts p3 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 260px;
  left: 130px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

/* Partners images */
.user1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 280px;
  left: 20px;
}

.user2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 280px;
  left: 90px;
}

.user3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 280px;
  left: 190px;
}

.user4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 280px;
  left: 290px;
}

.user5 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 280px;
  left: 390px;
}

.user6 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 280px;
  left: 480px;
}

/* Partners Names */
.NameLastname1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 200px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.NameLastname1 p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.NameLastname2 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 200px;
  margin-left: 305px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.NameLastname2 p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.NameLastname3 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 200px;
  margin-left: 615px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.NameLastname3 p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.NameLastname4 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 200px;
  margin-left: 920px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.NameLastname4 p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.NameLastname5 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 200px;
  margin-left: 1230px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.NameLastname5 p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.NameLastname6 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 200px;
  margin-left: 1525px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.NameLastname6 p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
}
/* Underlined text */
.roles1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 3%;
}

.roles2 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 19%
}

.roles3 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 37%;
}

.roles4 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 54%;
}

.roles5 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 72%;
}

.roles6 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 89%;
}
/* Forms */
.GoogleForms {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 40%;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  padding: 1% 3%;
}
/* Footer info */
.footer1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.CompanyInfo {
  padding-left: 120px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.CompanyInfo a {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-decoration: white;
          text-decoration: white;
  background-color: none;
}

.Policies {
  padding-left: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Policies a {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-decoration: white;
          text-decoration: white;
  background-color: none;
}

.Copyrights {
  padding-left: 29%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* phone home tab */
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .text-box h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .text-box p {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-links ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(128, 27, 27);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  #myimage {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    padding: 30px;
  }
  .footer1 {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  .CompanyInfo {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
  }
  .Policies {
    text-align: right;
    color: black;
  }
  .Copyrights {
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
  }
}
```
````

Comment: What do you mean by 'in the same place'? I should start by deciding what you want the layout to look like on different viewports - both viewports of different scales from your PC and viewports which are portrait rather than landscape.

Comment: I decided but i dont have a clue what to do next, yeah i did the css part, but what should i add or edit to be able to see everything like it is when i zoom out or zoom in?

Comment: Please include all your code, both HTML and CSS.

Comment: Included it but only the home page

Comment: Is your question about relative positionng on zoom or is it about layout for different viewport sizes/aspect ratios?

Comment: Its about different viewport sizes/ascpect ratios

Answer (score 0):

position fixed is the only thing will make your element display in the same place in all browser for example if your elment has this css code

```
.yourElment{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

in this case you will find your element in the top left corner of your website in all different device

Comment: Ive been using vw is that also needed or can i slide with writing in px?

Comment: Because ive been writing numbers with vw and it helped me

Comment: don't use vh or vw when you are position an items because vh vw you can not use it well to adjust items in right place it will be bad practice